# Will glue sticks form a barrier on a build surface to prevent PETG from damaging the surface?

Tags: heated-bed, petg, build-surface

Will glue sticks, such as **Elmer's All Purpose, Cra-Z-Art washable or Scotch Permanent**, form a barrier on a build surface to prevent PETG from damaging the surface?  While forming a barrier that holds the PETG print down, does it allow the PETG to separated after the print finishes, so that the build surface isn't damaged?

I found in the description of a glue stick designated for 3D-printers: "these 3D printer glue sticks can be applied to remove 3D models much easier .. made of quality PVP material ... have nice adhesion to hot plate or hot bed, easy to remove the printing models ..."

I'm now using an Elmer's washable school glue stick (PVP).  It is working consistently at bed temperatures of 30°C and 80°C. It both holds the PETG print and releases the print without destroying the build surface.

Comment: I don't know for glue sticks, but for 3DLAC (build adhesion spray) it is certainly true! I had a PEI sheet, where PETG used to almost fuse with, a layer of spray helped a lot to decrease the adhesion!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PVP but PVA sticks more at room temperature and gets weaker at higher temperatures, see ["Influence of temperature on the strength of bonded joints"](https://bioresources.cnr.ncsu.edu/resources/influence-of-temperature-on-the-strength-of-bonded-joints/)

[image]

I remember using hairspray with PVA for PETG and it was really difficult to detach large parts.

Comment: I'm not having trouble with PVP for PETG at 30° and 80°C.  Of course I was having trouble with PETG not releasing from the build surface without the PVP layer.  That seems to be the advertising point for glue stick selling for 3D printer use.

Comment: The PVA chart data is from wood joints in which the glue is applied wet and allowed to dry.  When used on a 3D printer bed, the glue is dry before the print and plastic is bonded to the dry PVA instead of wood.  Both are joints, but heating wood can have a drastic effect.